# Load package from notebook directory

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

How to import a file in the same directory as the current notebook?

I have tried

```
Get@FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "myPackage.wl"}
```

but get Get::noopen error

Edit: This command actually works,I am still thinking about other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The command you used is correct. If you see a `Get::noopen` error, then the file `myPackage.wl` does not exist in the same directory as the notebook. Take a look at the output of `FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "myPackage.wl"}`. Is there a file there? What does `FileExistsQ` say?

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to do so:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]

<< "subfolder/myPackage.wl"
```

Comment: I think if this works, the other approach would correctly be: Get@FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "subfolder","myPackage.wl"}. Also be aware that `SetDirectory` has set the directory also for all following evaluations, which very well might be what you want, anyway...